# Parse config file and convert array into nested hash

Tags: ruby

EDITED for clarification

I "had" done a number of searches (more than I can count) on google and apparently I wasn't searching with the right key words.  I found numerous sites (rubyforum, personal sites, stackoverflow, etc) none of which really addressed my particular issue and none of which I was able to adapt.

I am **parsing a config file** that has sections and subsections. That is, it's a file I pull from a device, not one that I can creating.  I want to create a hash of that config that has sections and subsections for quick access to a key or a subkey so that if I know the index of a given MAC, I can quickly set its status to disabled instead of having to iterate over the string or array version of config looking for MAC and tracking index.

Config file contents (in part) I want to convert from:  i.e. I'll read in the file and covert to hash.

```
aaa.1.br.devname=br0
aaa.1.devname=ath0
bridge.1.devname=br0
wireless.1.mac_acl.1.comment=testsm
wireless.1.mac_acl.1.mac=DC:9F:DB:32:0A:2E
wireless.1.mac_acl.1.status=enabled
wireless.1.mac_acl.policy=allow
wireless.1.mac_acl.status=enabled
```

What I want to convert it to:

```
{
 :aaa => {:"1" => {
                   :br => {:devname => "br0"},
                   :devname => "ath0"
                  }
         },
 :bridge => {:"1" => {:devname => "br0"}},
 :wireless => {:"1" => {
                         :mac_acl => {
                                      :"1" => {:comment => "testsm", :mac => "DC:9F:DB:32:0A:2E", :status => "enabled"}
                                     },
                        :policy => "allow",
                        :status => "enabled"
                       }
              }
}
```

'Edgars Jekabsons' provided two possible solutions (Thank you!!).  Configatron wouldn't work as many of the keys in the config I am parsing are/would be integers, Configatron doesn't like that.  It somewhat worked using the .store and .fetch methods, but updating an existing stored value was a problem.  Hashquiz was exactly what I was looking for... fantastic!

Sorry I didn't run across it in my many searches, I would like to have!  I do feel an assumption was made that I didn't search good enough or at all.  And the responses harsh.  This should be a friendly place whereby a measure of respect is exhibited and the initial assumption does not lean toward the negative.  I understand there should be some research done before posting and that questions should be clear.  However, what's clear to one individual is not to another.  An appropriate question may have been "I don't understand you question, can you clarify what you mean by...?" or "is the config you are parsing one that you created or are pulling from another source?", vs your question isn't clear.  My response, respectfully, is... what isn't clear?  Happy to clarify.  I, again, thought that the "From" this format (where I had already stated I was parsing a file")... "To" that format (hash) was self explanatory.

Not trying to be a jerk here or ungrateful, but come on guys.  I feel the problem was as much not reading the question as it was my not making it clear for some of you.

Best regards

Comment: Looks like someone edited your post (or you did) and someone down-voted it. It was a bit confusing. Better to give part of your explanation, then some code to illustrate rather than a long confusing explanation and then a lot of code. Right off the bat I think you might want to consider using some sort of existing system like JSON or YAML.

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted this, but I think you'll need to clarify your question in order to get help with this. See the help section for information on constructing questions to maximize a chance of getting a response.

Comment: Yes, something along the lines of.. I have this data <example data> that I would like to encode like this: <example encoding>, and be able to access like this: <example of how to access data>.

Comment: @Beartech/@Peter Alfvin - With all due respect, too often a poster is thrashed for not providing too little or too much.  I thought my "From" "To" was explanation enough... I added to two other examples so one could see what I wanted in action.  The source is the source, I cannot get in on any other format.

Comment: And can whoever downvoted my post explain why?  I look to stackoverflow often and get great results.  This is a total slap in the face!

Comment: Good luck with the down-vote thing. It drives me nuts that people can down-vote without having to own up to it. I guess they don't want people "going to war" with each other. One of my least favorite aspects of StackOverflow. Sure it costs to down-vote, but the people with 10,000+ points don't care, and it seems like they will down-vote a question of someone who is new and can barely afford it. Some questions are blatantly bad, but I just found your first paragraph a bit confusing because you piled so much info into it. It's always easier for the person who's problem it is to understand it.

Comment: @Beartech actually it only costs rep to downvote an answer, people can downvote questions for free.

Answer (score 1):

Well, If You would have searched a bit more, You would probably end up finding this gist:

https://gist.github.com/potatosalad/760726

Does exactly what You want. Not a bad alternative to consider:

https://github.com/markbates/configatron

Comment: Thank you, configatron looks like it might do the trick.  Very much appreciated.  Respectfully, I did search... for several days... sorry I ended up not finding a solution, no crystal ball here.